# how can i resolve this matter "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Map = function() {
  this.map = new Object();
};
Map.prototype = {
  put: function(key, value) {
    this.map[key] = value;
  },
  get: function(key) {
    return this.map[key];
  }
}; //skip details

 var _members = new Array(5);
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     var map = new Map();
     map.put("id", "hello");
     _members[i] = map;
   }

for (var i = 0; i < _members.length; i++) {
  var m = new Map();
  m = _members[i];
  alert(m.get("id")); //oops

}
```

Please help me.
I want use hashmap in arrays. but the error was encounted alert() line
whatever it was encounted using pop()
I dont know what can i do. wait for kind answer :)

Comment: Works just fine for me ?

Comment: you are overwriting `m` when you do `m = _members[i];` It is no longer a `new Map()` from prior line but you already pushed a `new Map()` into array. get rid of `var m = new Map()`

Comment: that right. I knew it. but how can i use a map object of arrays?  this isnt work too    `m = new Map(_members[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to implement standard data types, which is already exists in Javascript.

Try use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from `es2015`.

But if you insist on its implementation, it will work:

```
MyMap = function() {
  this.map = new Object();
};
MyMap.prototype = {
  put: function(key, value) {
    this.map[key] = value;
  },
  get: function(key) {
    return this.map[key];
  }
}; //skip details

 var _members = new Array(5);
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     var map = new MyMap();
     map.put("id", "hello");
     _members[i] = map;
   }

for (var i = 0; i < _members.length; i++) {
  m = _members[i];
  alert(m.get("id")); // no oops
}
```